# Returning a PartialView and a Model using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So what I want is pretty simple:
I want to display data from a partial View via ajax. In my partial View I'm using a Model, to fill a table with data.

**My Ajax**

```
var serviceURL = '/Vm/GetVMInformation';

$.ajax({
    url: serviceURL,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Success");
        $("#testDiv8").html(result);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**My Controller Action**

```
public ActionResult GetVMInformation()
{
    ... Code that fills my VmList with data ...
    return View("~/Views/Shared/_List.cshtml", VmList);
}
```

**My Partial View**

```
@model IsolutionsAzureManager.Models.VmData

<table class='table' id='vmTable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>VM Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Shutdown Time</th>
        <th>Service Name</th>
        <th>Created Date</th>
        <th>Last Modified</th>
        <th>Port</th>
    </tr>

    @for (int i = 0; i < @ViewData["SizeOfList"]; i++)
    {
        <tr class="tableColumn vmColumn">

            <td class="vmName">@Model.Name[i]</td>
            <td class="vmStatus">@Model.Status[i]</td>
            <td class="vmShutDown">@Model.Name[i]</td>
            <td class="vmServiceName">@Model.Name[i]</td>
            <td class="vmCreatedDate">@Model.Name[i]</td>
            <td class="vmLastModified">@Model.Name[i]</td>
            <td class="vmPort">@Model.Name[i]</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

So all this seems to be pretty clear. My problem is: Ajax only expects `html` as a return value. So I'm getting an "Internal Server" Error.
I've seen it would easily work with ViewBag's. But I think its not the best way to solve this.
So how can I add my data from my Model to my PartialView and then display it in my main View (where my Ajax is)

Thank you

Comment: This error means your *controller* failed, not the browser. I suspect, it's because you specified the path to the View instead of the view name, but you should debug your code to see why it crashes.

Comment: Just on a sidenote, in `return View("~/Views/Shared/_List.cshtml", VmList);` you're using `VmList` as the Model, but your partial view uses a Model called `VmData`.  Is this correct?  If not, you may want to instantiate a new `VmData` object and add `VmList` to it instead (if `VmList` is a property of `VmData`) before returning the ViewResult.

Comment: VmList is just a List of VmData objects

`List<VmData> VmList = new List<VmData>();`

So I did everything what @PanagiotisKanavos said. But it still gives me an Internal Server error

Comment: I've only done this once but I *think* in your server-side action you need to return `PartialView(...)`, not `View`

Comment: @PhilPursglove I tried this too. But it didnt work for me.
Is the return type and content type `html` in my Ajax function correct?

Comment: Well firstly try going to the url directly instead off in ajax, so you can see the _actual_ error. Second as alex said `VmData` isn't the same as a `List<VmData>` so you need to pass a single `VmData` to your `return View()` call